# G Suite Users:get and Users:list resources are not updated at the same time

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am currently using the G Suite Admin SDK API to retrieve user data. I want to check how long it takes for the user properties/fields to update.

After some checks I have realized that the User resources provided by the APIs [Users:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) and [Users:list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) are not updated at the same time (I have checked this and I can tell that there is at least an offset of several minutes).

Is this the expected behaviour?

In order to reproduce this issue you can do as follows:

1. Choose a Google user of your own.
2. Log into the user account (log out first if you are already logged in)
3. Check the API results for [Users:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) and [Users:list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). Specifically look for the `lastLoginTime` parameter value.

The expected `lastLoginTime` value should be:

```
"2020-05-22T10:09:04.000Z"
```

However, this is what I get:

For `Users:list`:

```
"lastLoginTime": "2020-05-21T09:25:33.000Z",
```

For `Users:get`:

```
"lastLoginTime": "2020-05-22T10:09:04.000Z",
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been also posted at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157227987.

Comment: Sounds like a propagation issue of some kind which is always expected, though from my tests it seems to update fairly quickly (within a minute).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because either opinion based or a bug neither of which can be answered on SO.   SO cant tell you what "googles definition of Expected behavior is"

Comment: @RafaGuillermo In my case it took more than a few hours to update. I would like to wait for a formal response from the G Suite team so we can all know exactly what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Can you please let me know, how are you pulling the data? Are you using the admin credentials or service account? I am struck here, help appreciated

Comment: @SharathKirani I am using the admin credentials (G Suite Administrator Seed Role). The process I am following is: 1) Log into my Google Account, 2) Visit the Users:list page (see question), provide the 'domain' field and click EXECUTE, 3) Visit the Users.get page (see question), provide the 'userKey' field and click EXECUTE. What I see is the 'lastLoginTime' field differs from the results in 2) and 3).  As RafaGuillermo mentioned, it looks like a propagation issue.